# How to make script with rsync better

Tags: shell, scripting, rsync

I have the following script using `rsync` for backuping and synchronization of my files.

How can I make this script more compact, faster and with better error handling?

```
#!/bin/sh
  
errors=""

sudo rsync -avh --delete --no-o --no-g /home/xralf/audio /media/extdevice/rsync_backups/
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
  echo "no errors in audio"
else
  errors="${errors}error in audio\n"
fi

sudo rsync -avh --delete --no-o --no-g /home/xralf/books /media/extdevice/rsync_backups/
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
  echo "no errors in books"
else
  errors="${errors}error in books\n"
fi

sudo rsync -avh --delete --no-o --no-g /home/xralf/source_code /media/extdevice/rsync_backups/
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
  echo "no errors in source_code"
else
  errors="${errors}error in source_code\n"
fi

# more such directories with this code pattern

echo ${errors}
```

Later I plan not to watch the script execution, so I'd like to see only the result and believe everything went right.
I ran the script, but in the end, the only information I have is `error in source_code`, and I can't see, what exactly the error is (which file caused it).

Comment: Does it need to be `sh` or can you use `bash`?

Comment: @terdon I think I can use bash. I haven't scripted much in my life, so far, so don't know the pros and cons.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/723309/100397

Comment: @roaima This question was first. You solved for me the speed. Thanks a lot. Here I would like to solve a bit better error handling yet. The existing answer is on a good way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your priority is to be **compact** and **fast** (ie: minimizing the number of processes, but in this case you are limited by your disk IOs, not by cpu or memory):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo rsync -a --delete --no-o --no-g \
       /home/xralf/{audio,books,source_code} \
       /media/extdevice/rsync_backups/ &&
    echo "rsync completed successfully" 1>&2 || echo "rsync ended with errors" 1>&2
```

Removing the `-v` option will make the output less noisy, so that you can focus on explicit errors, if any. The `1>&2` redirects STDOUT to STDERR, so that error messages are sent where expected. If running unattended, the following alternatives may be better options than the built-in `echo`, at the cost of on extra process:

1. a server can use `logger` to send the message to `syslog` for centralized handling. Exact syntax will depend of the server configuration.
2. using `date` to add timing information, with the last line of the script becoming:

```
date +"[%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S] rsync completed successfully" 1>&2 || \
date +"[%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S] rsync ended with errors" 1>&2
```

to output something like `[2022/12/05 14:37:27] rsync completed successfully`

Comment: So, I have to check for errors something like this? `tail /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @xralf If you use logger, the messages will be send to the syslog daemon. Depending of the priority and category you used when sending the message, it will be added in a specific file (or other specific actions, like sending message on a remote server). /var/log/syslog usually contains most messages. Check the manual for syslog.conf https://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf for more info. While using syslog is a good practice for system management, it is a topic on itself, beyond the scope of the initial question.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not forced to use `sh` but can use a more complex shell like `bash`, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=( "audio" "books" "source_code" );
errors=()
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  sudo rsync \
       -avh --delete --no-o --no-g \
       /home/xralf/"$dir" \
       /media/extdevice/rsync_backups/ &&
    echo "no errors in $dir" ||
      errors+=("error in $dir\n")
done

printf '%s\n' "${errors[@]}"
```

You probably also want to capture stderr but this does the same thing as your script.

Comment: Thanks. And is this model of error handling sufficient or is there a better way? Is it possible to make if faster? I heard about the `--whole-file` switch but don't understand what it does, so I'm afraid using it.

Comment: Later I plan not to watch the script execution, so I'd like to see only the result and believe everything went right. I would like to even enter the password only once (at the beginning). Now I have to repeatedly enter the password.

Comment: I ran the script, but in the end, the only information I have is `error in source_code`, and I can't see, what exactly the error is.

Comment: @xralf whether you can make it faster will depend very much on the kind of disks you are writing to/reading from, but sure, if your disk supports it you can parallelize the execution. To only enter the password once, remove `sudo` from the rsync commands and just run the script itself with `sudo script.sh`. As for the last, yes, that's why I said you probably want to capture the stderr but your original didn't do that and you didn't explain you needed it so I didn't know. Please edit your question and add all requirements there.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: Using  : printf '%s\n' "${errors[@]}" 1>&2 will redirect errors printing to STDERR rather than to STDOUT, which is usually good practice. Note that you can do pretty much the same in pure sh.

Answer (score 1):

The `rsync` command accepts the parameter `--log-file=FILE`. You can examine it for errors when the backup is complete.

For efficiency's sake, it also accepts `--exclude-from=FILE` and `--include-from=FILE`. You can create text files containing a list of everything you **do** and **do not** want to back up and call them from a single `rsync` command rather than multiple ones.

See `man rsync` or [the online man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

Answer (score 0):

Make a file called *module.sh* and give it the following text:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                     

# -A=Archive. Use recursion and preserve almost everything.
# -V=Verbose.
# -H=Preserve hard links.
# -Z=Compress.
# --Delete=
#     If node in directory 'from' gets deleted,
#     delete it in directory 'to'.
# --No-o=No Owner. 
# --No-g=No Group.
# The --No's are partially undoing the Archive option.

sync_dir(){
    local from="${1}";
    local to="${2}";

    rsync               \
        -avhz           \
        --delete        \
        --no-o          \
        --no-g          \
            "${from}/"  \
            "${to}"     \
        1>/dev/null     \
        ;

    # Store the sync success.
    local sync_result="${?}";

    # The project name is the last directory of the from string.
    local project_name=$(grep -oE '[^/]*$' <<<"${from}");

    local error="No error in: ${project_name}";
    if [ "${sync_result}" -ne "0" ]; then
        error="Error in: ${project_name}\n";
        fi  
    printf "${error}\n";
    };
```

Then you make another file and source the module from there:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
                                                                       
. ./module.sh;

sync_dir '/home/xralf/audio' '/media/extdevice/rsync_backups/';
# More sync dirs here.
```

Note different Shebang, this one is POSIX compliant.

I also added Rsync's -z option. It compresses the data en route.

Comment: You cannot call a function that is defined afterwards.

Comment: Fixed. .........