# rsync --whole-file explained

Tags: rsync

When I run `rsync` from my hard drive to a mounted flash drive it's quite slow. I'm thinking about using `--whole-file` switch.

Could you explain, why it's faster? Why shouldn't I be afraid using it? And what are the pros and cons of using it. I haven't found much information about it.

rsync command:

```
rsync -avh --delete --no-o --no-g /home/xralf/audio /media/extdevice/rsync_backups/
```

I `rsync` from harddrive (ext4 filesystem) to flash drive (vfat filesystem).

Comment: Quite slow ? compared to what ? What are source and destination filesystem's support ? OF course you should not be "afraid" of using it… since… its default when source and destination are local paths.

Comment: @MC68020 I rsync from my hard drive to the mounted flash drive.

Comment: I lived with slow flash drives. USB3 flash drives with USB3 ports were a bit faster. Then I got an external SSD. Actually my old SSD with SATA to USB adapter. It is almost as fast as it was as an internal drive. I have lots of flash drives, but will now not buy anymore. Also note FAT32 not recommended for backup. It does not have journal, cannot have file over 4GB and does not support Linux ownership & permissions. You will lose all the settings you are trying to copy with the -a option in rsync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the documentation for `--whole-file` (`-W`) found on your system with `man rsync`, which first explains what it does:

> This option disables `rsync`'s delta-transfer algorithm, which causes all transferred files to be sent whole.

and then goes on to say that,

> The transfer may be faster if this option is used when the bandwidth  between  the source  and  destination  machines  is  higher  than the bandwidth to disk (especially when the "disk" is actually a networked filesystem). […]

There are fundamentally two modes of operation for `rsync`.

1. Local copies (including network filesystems where both source and destination *look like* they are part of the local filesystem). In this instance `rsync` chooses to copy an entire file or skip it, depending on the file size and modification timestamp. The `--whole-file` option is enabled in this situation, so there is no incremental optimisation. Indeed, almost all of the time it would make no sense to enable this as you'd spend longer reading the source and destination files to compare them than just copying the file in the first place.
2. Remote copies (where one path contains `{host}:{path}` or `{host}::{path}` style constructs). In this situation `rsync` can run one instance of itself on the local machine and one on the remote. These two instances can independently read the source and target file to compare them, hopefully resulting in the optimised case that only changes are transmitted across the network. Here, `--whole-file` is not enabled by default.

In scenario #1, the `--whole-file` option is enabled by default and will lead to file copies that are almost always faster than incremental transfers. (The exception is if you can read a local disk *significantly* faster than you can write to it.)

This is the situation that you are using (local to local copy). The big problem here is that you're writing to a VFAT filesystem, which has only two-second granularity on its file timestamps. This means that for many files `rsync` will consider them to be out of date and will recopy them - needlessly.

**The fix here** is to use `--modify-window=1` (see the documentation, `man rsync`, for the detail). [I have also read](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2018-January/031454.html) that if you are in a timezone that changes between summer and winter you should run the `rsync` command under UTC to avoid associated timezone complications, but I have not tested this myself:

```
TZ=UTC rsync -rtvh --modify-window=1 --delete /home/xralf/audio /media/extdevice/rsync_backups/
```

In scenario #2, the `--whole-file` option is disabled by default and will lead to incremental file transfers that are usually faster than sending the whole file without care. The exception is when sending data across the network is faster than computing the differences between source and destination; this could be the case on 10Gb/s networks, for example.

Conclusion: in general, trying to cheat `rsync`'s built-in optimisation won't make things any better, and often can make transfer speeds far worse. Neither enable nor disable `--whole-file`, but rather just let `rsync` choose for itself. As far as VFAT filesystems go, though, try to avoid them but if you can't then this is a situation where you do need to give `rsync` some extra help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems to me slow. I rsync about 20G  and it takes about 20 minutes to check the files are already (most of them) in the destination. So, I can't make it faster? I assume that in the future, I won't watch the progress, only rsync result.

Comment: @xralf : What are the filesystems of source & destination ? Some FAT for the flashdrive ? Connected to USB 2? 3?

Comment: @roaima I edited the question.

Comment: @xralf answer updated accordingly

Comment: @roaima It seems that `--modify-window=1` helped a lot. Now, it's a matter of a few seconds :-)